# ANTLRv4 reset lexer and parser after an error

Tags: antlr4

I was trying to reuse a lexer/parser to sequentially parse short chunks of text. To be sure that no remains of a previous run will remain I always do

```
    mLexer.reset();
    mLexer.setInputStream(new ANTLRInputStream(data));

    mParser.reset();
    mParser.setTokenStream(new CommonTokenStream(mLexer));
```

thinking that this will completely reset both lexer and parser no matter what happened before. Unfortunately some things remain when parsing invalid patterns.

My lexer does not recover:

```
      @Override
        public void recover(final LexerNoViableAltException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

My parser won't either:

```
private class HexParserErrorStrategy extends org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy {
    @Override
    public void recover(final Parser recognizer, final RecognitionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    @Override
    public Token recoverInline(final Parser recognizer) throws RecognitionException {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Override
    public void reportUnwantedToken(final Parser recognizer) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

When I parse a string like "123456" this works nicely. Afterwards I parse an invalid pattern, which gives me a RE. If i try to parse "123456" again, the results are different than those of the first run.

So how can I reset my parser/lexer accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the ordering of setXXStream and reset are important. When reversing the order it works as expected:

```
mLexer.setInputStream(new ANTLRInputStream(data));
mLexer.reset();

mParser.setTokenStream(new CommonTokenStream(mLexer));
mParser.reset();
```

Might be something for the docs. Originally I would have expected the lexer/parser to be resetted when a new stream is set.

Answer (score 1):

*How* are the results different from the first run?

Here are some general tips:

1. Use `BailErrorStrategy` instead of creating your own. It's already included in the ANTLR runtime and will throw a `ParseCancelledException` instead of just `RuntimeException`. It also sets the `exception` field of all relevant parse tree nodes to the proper value.
2. You can create a new lexer/parser instance instead of reusing a previous one.

Comment: During the invalid run I have unknown characters in my stream. This is detected correctly. On the third run I still get the error that some characters are not recognized correctly.

Comment: Regarding using a new parser. That was my workaround so far. I just thought as parsers learn and get faster over time; I wanted to reuse it.

Comment: The DFA is a shared structure, so new parser instances automatically reuse the results of previous ones.